# Deleting "lonely" points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity

I have a large point dataset of about 5.3 million points. I would like to delete the "lonely" points using QGIS, for example all points with no neighbor within a 5 km radius. The extent of my point dataset limits some of the tools I guess...

I tried the Distance matrix en v.neighbours tools, but QGIS can't handle it and goes irresponsive... Is there another way to work around this problem for large datasets?

[image]

Comment: Make a dissolved Buffer and then delete those with area of a single buffer or less than something, in particular can be <= 5 km

Comment: Do you think this would work with such a large dataset?

Comment: Irresponsive?  Maybe you're just impatient :)  Under Windows, open the Task Manager to see the QGIS CPU usage; that will inform you if QGIS is still chugging away at the task.

Comment: As a rule, it's often better to keep features you don't want to delete during a copy than to delete features (and their indexes) directly..

Comment: Quick possibility (haven't listed the commands so I wouldn't regard it as an answer) - buffer the points to 5km, then do a "count nodes in polygon" on the buffer. Ensure that there is some sort of primary key to link it back to the original layer. Link it back using a join, then delete any where the counted nodes =1 (as it will still contain the original node).

Comment: @user25730, smart suggestion. I think in my case the area would not be that much stable as the number of points inside a polygon. Because if those points are spread  within a large area means at each latitude (depends on datum) most likely the area of a circle is not the same and could cause misinterpreting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand it, `v.neighbors` outputs a raster that can hold the number of points within a set distance from each cell, but does not identify whether or not the points themselves have any neighbours (see the [manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.neighbors.html)).

Anyway, instead you could try a clustering tool, for example `DBSCAN clustering`. Set the minimum cluster size to 2 and maximum distance to 5 km. Using the default settings, points without neighbours will then get CLUSTER_ID set to null in the attribute table.
If you then perform a selection using the expression `"CLUSTER_ID" != 'NULL'` and save the selected features, you should be left with a layer holding all points with at least one neighbour within 5 km (and still have the original data, as per the comment by Vince)